# Need React input box to be a floating number

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input

I need a simple input box to be a floating point number (anything with a `.` really). As it is right now, it doesn't allow me to put the dot and do a floating point. Should be simple but I can't find much on this.

Here is roughly the current code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <td>
        <label> Value: </label>
            <input
                type='number'
                min='0'
                max='20'
                className='form-control'
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange= {(evt) => this.onValueChange('value', evt.target.value)}
              />
      </td>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `step="any"`.

Comment: @Everettss it works but there is an error that step accepts only number, string is invalid type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number type has a `step` value controlling which numbers precision which defaults to `1`.

You can use this to set the floating point precision

```
<input type="number" step="0.1">
```

You will have

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <td>
        <label> Value: </label>
            <input
                type='number'
                step="0.1"
                min='0'
                max='20'
                className='form-control'
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange= {(evt) => this.onValueChange('value', evt.target.value)}
              />
      </td>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize this.state.value to 0 if its undefined, you might get this error